# How can I set the access-point priority in a netplan configuration?

Tags: networking, wireless, netplan, wpa-supplicant

Which is the correct netplan-property for defining priority between access-points?

I'm using access point configurations like this:

```
# /etc/netplan/netplan.yaml

  ...

  wifis:
    wlo1:
      access-points:
        "mywifi":
          password: "mypassword"
```

Which generates a wpa_supplicant configuration:

```
# /run/netplan/wpa-wlo1.conf

ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
  ssid="mywifi"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  psk="mypassword"
}
```

When using wpa_supplicant by itself it is easy to define a priority order with for example **priority=3** in that network paragraph.

There has to be a way to do this but I cannot find it in FAQs or manuals.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this feature is not implemented in netplan (neither for networkd nor for networkmanager backend).